# Mount both sides of ZFS mirror to different mountpoints (AKA Glusterfs is choking)

Tags: zfs, sas, mirroring, raidz, jbod

We have two `SuperStorage Server 6049PE1CR36L` each with 24 - 4TB disks. At the moment we are running `Ubuntu 18.04` but this is negotiable if it helps solve our problem. We are using `Ext4` as the OS filesystem, and `OpenZFS` for the data. We have an HBA, not a hardware RAID controller.

ZFS currently dos not support mirroring across a network (ETH). We are considering **cross-linking the the JBODs to each other, so each OS recognizes the other's hard drives (and ZFS filesystem.)** We have tested this already, and this is possible via the hardware.

The ZFS mirror would use a stripe/raidz of drives on *one* JBOD, mirrored to a stripe/raidz of drives on the *second* JBOD.

**The question is; is it possible to mount BOTH sides of the mirror (the server built into each JBOD is attached to it's side of the mirror) so that - in the event of a failover, the second mount could seamlessly begin being used?**

[image: Crosslinked Servers with JBOD]

As an aside, the reason we are considering this is because we were using `Glusterfs` as a distributed filesystem to handle the mirroring, **but the performance is literally 1/10 what we should be getting**.

We are not sure why, so if anyone has ideas about that issue - please feel free.